Network controller is not available from time to time
Sometimes Network controller is not visible via lspci.
And nmcli shows only unmanaged lo loopback device: system can't connect any wifi.
But for other networks everything is ok.
First time this helped, but in next cases it doesn't.
It does not depend on specific network and time.
Reboots of Network Manager and all system don't help too.
No other operating systems are using on machine.
What can cause such problem? no ideas (maybe some recent updates are the reason? How to check this?)
6.8.0-47-generic
Thanks!

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

Would be helpful to know what network controller it is and how it is connnected. Please run the command "lshw -C network" and and post result here.
